# Laravel - Getting NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 for each controller

Tags: php, laravel

I just moved my project to a new server.

I did the following:

```
composer update
php artisan migrate
php artisan cache:clear
```

But Im getting this error message:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

for each controller. Any idea why ?

[UPDATE]

This is the content of the  routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/orders', 'OrdersController@index');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/shipments', 'ShipmentsController@index');
});
```

This works fine on localhost, but not on the new server for some reason.

[UPDATE] - .htaccess from the public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your routes file and the location of your controllers?

Comment: @Jerodev, I updated my post, please check it . thx

Comment: On your new server, can you run `php artisan route:list` and check  the output to verify that routes files is getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your routes defined into route declaration, make sure you have defined a route for the url you are trying to access.

**EDIT**

Could you please update your question with `.htaccess` code? may be some problem with this. Means that your url something like `www.example.com/laravel` then your route should start with laravel not `/`.

**UPDATE** 
*routes/web.php*

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/orders', 'OrdersController@index');
    Route::get('/shipments', 'ShipmentsController@index');
});
```

Make change for combine route group.

Comment: Srry, i don't get your answer , can you give more details ? or an example maybe ? thx I have to mentioned that is works fine on my local, but not on the  server :|

Comment: See my EDIT and if possible, update your question with same.

Comment: I added the htaccess to my post

Comment: @AttilaNaghi Check *UPDATE*